# iphone jailbroken development with public API

Tags: ios, jailbreak, nsfilemanager, abaddressbook

I have an app that is using the `ABAdressBook` API & `NSFileManager`.

When i'm running the application from the command line - the API doesn't seems to retrieve 
the `AddressBook/NSFileManager` information - but when i run it from the springboard - it does show me the information required.

Is it because my app doesn't have a UI when it run from the command line?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    @autoreleasepool 
    {
        printf("HELLO TEST\n");       
        NSLog(@"---------");
        NSMutableArray* dbList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSLog(@"file manager address is %@",fileManager);
        NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirnum = [fileManager enumeratorAtPath: @"/private/"];
        NSLog(@"dirNum is %@",dirnum);
        NSString *nextItem = [NSString string];

        while( (nextItem = [dirnum nextObject])) {
            if ([[nextItem pathExtension] isEqualToString: @"db"] ||
                [[nextItem pathExtension] isEqualToString: @"sqlitedb"]) {
                if ([fileManager isReadableFileAtPath:nextItem]) {
                    [dbList addObject:nextItem];

                    NSLog(@"%@", nextItem);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**  I pinned the issue down to the following selector:
[fileManager isReadableFileAtPath:nextItem]
when i run this function from the SpringBoard - it returns true - for several of the files...

when i run it in the command line - it return false to all of the files - although i'm running the app with root privileges.

any idea what can cause this change in behavior?

Thanks,
Itay

Answer (score 1):

Both `ABAddressBook` and `NSFileManager` have a class method that returns a unique, shared object – in your code above, the call to `[NSFileManager defaultManager]` retrieves "the default `NSFileManager` object for the file system", according to the docs. When you run your app from the command line, you're probably not executing some or all of the code that *initializes* the shared object; you may even be getting back `nil` from the class method.

If so, you may be able to work around this problem by creating your own object (that is, by using `[[NSFileManager alloc] init]` or `[ABAddressBook addressBook]`) rather than relying on the class method to return a shared object.

Comment: Will the [ABAddressBook addressBook] return me the address book of the device? filled with the address book contacts? or it will be an empty one?

Comment: i can't seem to call  [ABAddressBook addressBook] the compiler doesn't find this function.

Comment: `[ABAddressBook addressBook]` is a class method, which means that you call it from the class itself – that is, your code should use the exact literal string `[ABAddressBook addressBook]`. `[myInstanceVariable addressBook]` doesn't work. The documentation is a little fuzzy on whether the address book returned by `[ABAddressBook addressBook]` can be used to search for existing records – it does say that if you write to that address book and then save, the results will show up in the user's address book.

Comment: didn't managed to compile it. (gone the other road for now..accessing the db directly)